# Android Studio Linked with IntelliJ Gradle projects

Tags: intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

So im pretty new in Java/Android development, and i started to learn Gradle. I have 2 Projects:

- Android application using Gradle and Android Studio
- Java library using Gradle and IntelliJ

I know i am probably not doing best practices (because i still don't know them i come from PHP) but my problem is this:

When i change my Java library and build the .jar file with ./gradlew build, i have to manually copy this .jar file into my /path/to/AndroidProject/lib folder.

Is there some automation possible with gradle for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Gradle has ways to configure project dependencies and automate the copying of jar files back and forth between dependencies. This is what you'd have to do:

1. You should make the main Android app and the library become modules of the same project. For that, create a `settings.gradle` file on the top-level folder that contains both app and library projects:

   root/

   - App1/
   - Library1/
   - settings.gradle

Then add these lines to `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':App1'
include ':Library1'
```

where `App1` and `Library1` are your projects. If you have multiple apps or libraries then you can add them too in this way.

2. The previous steps tells gradle that your project has various submodules, but you still have to tell it about the mutual dependencies. For that, go to the `build.gradle` file of your app project and tell it that it depends on the library:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile project(':Library1')
   }
   ```

   in addition to any dependencies that the project might have.

After you apply these steps, you won't have to copy jar files from the library to the main project - gradle will take care of that for you.